# Reference Request concerning Jet Bundles..

Tags: geometry, reference-request, differential-geometry, jet-bundles

can anyone recommend me a nice reference concerning jet bundles? I've been looking for one for a long time but I couldn't find it...Thanks..

Comment: Saunders'"The Geometry of Jet Bundles"

Comment: *Advanced Classical Field Theory* by G. Giachetta may be relevant though I am not very sure as this book is meant for Physicists.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check them..

Answer (score 3):

[Natural Operations in Differential Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540562354) by Kolar, Michor, and Slovak gives a comprehensive account of the theory of jets, and uses the concept throughout the text.